# Why am I hitting undefined, when deserializing a protocol 2 pickle file using Language.Python.Pickle.unpickle?

Tags: haskell, pickle

I'm trying to use **Language.Python.Pickle.unpickle**, from *python-pickle-0.2.3*, to deserialize a protocol 2 pickle archive, and am getting this:

```
undefined, called at ./Language/Python/Pickle.hs:175:44 in python-pickle-0.2.3-H8B4QMwzEy76HsmPt8HyK5:Language.Python.Pickle
```

Here is line 175 of *Pickle.hs*:

```
global = string "c" *> (uncurry GLOBAL <$> undefined)
```

Anyone know why it's calling undefined?

Comment: The package simply doesn't implement all features of the 'pickle' language (and instead of omitting parser entries for those features, it includes such entries that call 'undefined' - this is at the very least bad design, but more likely an incorrect implementation). In other words, there is never a case in which this code works if this parser is ever reached. (Aside: a better (i.e. more productive) question would be what 'pickle' is, what you're trying to use it to do, and why you need to interface with python using such a format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting `undefined` because the package is only a partial implementation.